# Refactor two one-to-one and one-to-many relationships in a single table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have following database schema (simplified).
[image: Database schema]

**Requirements**

- One account must have one sub-account
- One sub-account, depending on type, might have other sub-accounts (nested hierarchy).

**Problems I am having**

1. Database doesn't guarantee consistency, as I can insert account without a sub-account.
2. Joining account and the main sub-account might result in multiple rows if sub-account has other sub-accounts when only account and the main sub-account data is needed.
3. Need a way to identify main sub-accounts in the sub-accounts table. `ParentSubAccountId IS NULL` works but not sure if it's the cleanest way to do it.

**Notes**

- The main sub-account contains exactly the same fields, as other sub-accounts, hence was originally placed in the same table.
- Sub-account children could be retrieved as a flat list with parent sub-account IDs, and hierarchical structure will be restored at software layer.

**Options considered**

[image: Database schema 2]

This solves #1 and #2 problems, #3 stays the same, however I need to perform recursive select to retrieve all sub-accounts for an account.

**Questions**

Is there a better approach to improve database design than the option I've considered?

Comment: If you must deal with hierarchy, why don't use only one table?

Comment: I need to have two distinct and unique IDs exposed to identify account and each sub-account entities.

Comment: What DBMS is this for?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option I considered initially was a good start, just needed further improving. The schema of the solution is below.

[image]

The solution consists of two parts actually:

- Add unique constraint on `SubAccountId`
- Introduce table for `SubAccount` children hierarchy mapping, both columns have foreign key to `Id` of the `SubAccount` table.

Children nested hierarchy is restored at software layer, the adjacency list hierarchy was not really needed.